# How to copy input/output streams of the Process to their System counterparts?

Tags: java, process, io, stream, pipe

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60302/471164). The answer suggested there is

> to copy the Process out, err, and input streams to the System versions

with `IOUtils.copy` as follows (after fixing various compilation errors):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh -i");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {public void run() {
            try {
                IOUtils.copy(process.getInputStream(), System.out);
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        } } ).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {public void run() {
            try {
                IOUtils.copy(process.getErrorStream(), System.err);
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        } } ).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {public void run() {
            try {
                IOUtils.copy(System.in, process.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        } } ).start();
        process.waitFor();
    }
}
```

However, the resulting code doesn't work for interactive processes like the one executing `sh -i` command. In the latter case there is no response to any of the `sh` commands.

So my question is: could you suggest an alternative to copy the streams that will work with interactive processes?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `IOUtil.copy()` is running while there is data in the InputStream to be copied. Since your process only produces data from time to time, `IOUtil.copy()` exits as it thinks there is no data to be copied.

Just copy data by hand and use a boolean to stop the thread form outside:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while (threadRunning) {  // threadRunning is a boolean set outside of your thread
    if((len = input.read(buf)) > 0){
        output.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
}
```

This reads in chunks as many bytes as there are available on inputStream and copies all of them to output. Internally InputStream puts thread so `wait()` and then wakes it when data is available.
So it's as efficient as you can have it in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However `IOUtil.copy()` doesn't exit until the end of the stream has been reached so it is not that different from your code which has the same problems with `sh`.

Comment: Pls take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-java-inputstream-with-a-timeout/808795#808795

Answer (score 2):

`Process.getOutputStream()` returns a `BufferedOutputStream`, so if you want your input to actually get to the subprocess you have to call `flush()` after every `write()`.

You can also rewrite your example to do everything on one thread (although it uses polling to read both System.in and the process' stdout at the same time):

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestProcessIO {

  public static boolean isAlive(Process p) {
    try {
      p.exitValue();
      return false;
    }
    catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-i");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true); // so we can ignore the error stream
    Process process = builder.start();
    InputStream out = process.getInputStream();
    OutputStream in = process.getOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4000];
    while (isAlive(process)) {
      int no = out.available();
      if (no > 0) {
        int n = out.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(no, buffer.length));
        System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, n));
      }

      int ni = System.in.available();
      if (ni > 0) {
        int n = System.in.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(ni, buffer.length));
        in.write(buffer, 0, n);
        in.flush();
      }

      try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
    }

    System.out.println(process.exitValue());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should instead use the `ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput` method & friends. Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput%28java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect%29)