# Calling perl from java

Tags: java, perl

How do I call a perl script from java? Currently I have this code but a create process error =2 keeps coming up.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl C:/Users/Mahish/Documents/PLUa/src//test.pl");
```

Comment: Have you tried a full /path/to/perl ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272956/run-a-sub-process-provide-input-and-output-to-it-correctly-in-java

Comment: What error is sent to STDERR?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set full path to your dir `perl\bin`

Example command to do this in CMD:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\perl\bin
```

and after that you can use:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl C:/Users/Mahish/Documents/PLUa/src/test.pl");
```