# Reading input/output from Chatting program[exe file]

Tags: java, chatbot

**what i tried**

```
try {
    File fileDir = new File("B:\\Palringo\\palringo.exe");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(
              new FileInputStream("B:\\Palringo\\palringo.exe"), "UTF8"));

    String str;

    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

        in.close();
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

**Output** :

```
unreadable Strings
```

**what i want**

i want to control the (**palringo.exe**) so i can make Bot for it

**What is palringo.exe ?:**

its a chatting program you can download it or use web version (palringo.im).

am i doing wrong by opening a file that is exe ? should i connect to the website by Connection classes in java ? if so , how i can connect it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272956/run-a-sub-process-provide-input-and-output-to-it-correctly-in-java ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a sub process, provide input and output to it correctly in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272956/run-a-sub-process-provide-input-and-output-to-it-correctly-in-java)

Comment: its not what i asked for guys , but thanks for trying to help <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This doesn't work. You cannot read an exe file.**

You need to have the source code or library to add that software to you code. You simply cannot read a exe file and extract code, because exe file will be encrypted and it will be in lower level languages.

But you can use `exec()` to run that exe file.

Comment: so , can i extract the output by using Connection classes in java ?

Comment: rly thanks for trying to help , but i tried to do as he did but still no output

Comment: Welcome sir...what output are you expecting?

Comment: it should be whatever people writing in that (palringo.exe) program

Comment: You cannot do that... you can just run that program but cannot access its resources...by the way why do you want to use that?.. are you trying to build a chat application?

Comment: no sir , i want to do that so i can make a bot to solve mathematics problem if any user enter for example 1*2 , so my program should enter 2 in the same (palringo.exe) program

Comment: I am sorry... but I don't think you can do that... the problem is palringo is a third party apparently and you can't access it, unless palringo gives a SDK or some API

Comment: there is API https://www.nuget.org/packages/PalringoApi
 but it seems im noob enough that i dont know the commands ,and how i can import it to java

Comment: im rly sorry to bother you sir , thank you anyway <3

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late answer, if you are looking to connect and manipulate palringo, there are a couple of APIs available.

https://github.com/calico-crusade/PalringoApi

This specific one can also be found on Nuget, though it is for C#. You could copy over the majority of the connection code to Java if you wish.