# interacting with console(terminal in linux) window using Java

Tags: java

I am working on developing GUI for java programming.

I wish to implement a console (terminal like thing) in my GUI, for compiling and executing the programs created. ( like console window in eclipse ). I went through several tutorials (including **stackoverflow**).

I got some solutions to redirect the **System.out** and **System.err** to **TextArea**. Okay. I am happy with that.

But when I run a java program, by using these things, I can't give input to the program which is executing.

For example, with my present status, I can see::

Enter a Number: in **TextArea** but can't input to the program.

To complete the function of the console I could be able to give input to the program in execution too..!! But I dont know how to do that..!! I am in big trouble.

Comment: Give us some example code that you have. It is definitely possible, since Netbeans and Eclipse both provide such output windows.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-the-panel) link is having that program.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption is that you are working with a [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). To get a Process, start your programs with [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). The Process gives access to the process's in/out streams.  You can then use those streams in whatever way you need. If you want your process to interact with system in/out, then you will need to copy them to/from the corresponding System streams.

See this question/answer for an example:

- [Starting a process with inherited stdin/stdout/stderr in Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302/starting-a-process-with-inherited-stdin-stdout-stderr-in-java-6)

and the follow-up:

- [How to copy input/output streams of the Process to their System counterparts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177594/how-to-copy-input-output-streams-of-the-process-to-their-system-counterparts?lq=1)

Also, see the new [ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29) method that was added in Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/273874-redirect-systemin-to-jtextarea/

this guy has directed stdin to jtextarea..